# Rheostat controller for swamp cooler motor?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Will a rheostat variable controller work to slow the rpm’s in a single phase swamp cooler motor? I have it hard wired on the common and slow leads only, so it’s already on it’s low speed. I want it slower, hopefully with torque increase. Using it for a very non-conventional reason. Halloween prop.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the voltage may or may not reduce the speed, depending on the type of motor. However, it will not increase torque and will probably reduce it.

If you want lower speed and higher torque, you need to add reduction gears.